# How to show/hide another application's window(s)?

Tags: c#, java, vb.net

I want to create a button that can hide an exe application. As example: 
this application will start `spider.exe` when page loads.
I need a button that can hide & show the `spider.exe`.
How can I do it with VB.NET, C#, or Java?

I tried to use

```
myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle =  System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
myProcess.Start()
```

in page load part, and use

```
myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle =  System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
```

in button part but it does not work

Comment: Process.StartInfo.WindowStyle only affects the properties of the process when it starts, it has no effect after the processes has started.

Comment: this sounds like somthing "bad"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use PInvoke and call API [ShowWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.showwindow) passing the other app window handle and proper parameters to show or hide.